# How to play 2 videos one after the other in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to play intro video just once followed by another video which loops. I have this code to detect when first video ends but how do i load the second video and set it to play in loop?

```
const vidIndex = 0;
const videos = [videoIntro, videoLoop];
return (
    <div className="main">
        <video src = {videos[vidIndex]} autoPlay muted onEnded={() => vidIndex++} />
    </div>
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a `useState` to track the video index. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-monad-wl1ycu?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const videoIntro = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4";
const videoLoop =
  "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4";

function App() {
  const [vidIndex, setVidIndex] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (vidIndex === 0 && ref.current) {
      ref.current.play();
    }
  }, [ref, vidIndex]);
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <video
        style={{ display: vidIndex === 1 ? "none" : "block" }}
        src={videoIntro}
        autoPlay
        muted
        onEnded={() => setVidIndex((idx) => idx + 1)}
      />
      <video
        style={{ display: vidIndex === 0 ? "none" : "block" }}
        src={videoLoop}
        muted
        loop
        ref={ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works great, but it flashes momentarily when loading the second video. I would like the transition to be smooth as if it was the same video playing. Any idea on how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: @makul I've updated my answer but such requirements would be appreciated in the question. Since you only have one video element, of course it's going to have to pause to load the second video.

Comment: Thank you very much and apologies for incorrect description.